# NativeScript Angular: An Uncaught Exception Occurred on main thread on android

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am new to mobile development and I am working with NativeScript and in the Android application I find this error.

[image]

[Here's my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RENIx.png)

Comment: try removing and re adding platform again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tns platform remove android/ios
 tns platform add android/ios
 tns run android/ios`

if not... try to delete your `node_modules` folder and execute `npm install` or `npm i`

Comment: Both solutions don't work... The error continue... But, thanks!

Comment: Can i see whats inside your `package.json`?

Comment: Sure ! @JannoTabamo, I have edited my question to put the image of the Package.json file. It's like a link below the first image

Comment: try also to update your `tns-core-modules` to `v4.0.1`

Answer (score -1):

I using command

> tns run android/ios -env.aot